# Sharing dictionary data between tests

Tags: specflow, automated-tests

I have the following scenario in Specflow:

```
Scenario Outline: K_KRED_FIELD - validation
    Given that K_KRED_FIELD has value <value>
    And that K_STATUS_FIELD has value <value_status>
    When I run rule K_KRED_RULE
    Then value of this field is <validation_result>

Examples: 
    | value         | value_status| validation_result |
    | 0.00          | Cancelled   | valid             |
    | 0.00          |             | invalid           |
```

The general idea is as follows: I check if the value of field `K_KRED_FIELD` is valid, depending on value of other field - `K_STATUS_FIELD` using rule `K_KRED_RULE`. I have many fields and many rules like that.

Field `K_STATUS_FIELD` has many valid values (around 50). Of course it's possible to create example for each of those values but it's time-consuming and some other fields are dependent of `K_STATUS_FIELD`, so for each of them I need around 50 examples.

Is it possible to create something like a dictionary with valid values of `K_STATUS_FIELD` and run test against each of them? I was thinking about something like

```
Scenario Outline: K_KRED_FIELD - validation
    Given that K_KRED_FIELD has value <value>
    And that K_STATUS_FIELD value is valid
    When I run rule K_KRED_RULE
    Then value of this field is <validation_result>

Examples: 
    | value         |  validation_result |
    | 0.00          |  valid             |
    | 0.00          |  invalid           |
```

where `And that K_STATUS_FIELD value is valid` iterates over each valid value for field `K_STATUS_FIELD` with each value `K_KRED_FIELD` taken from the `Examples` table.

Comment: I would like to question why there are 50 possible values you wish to test against. Do you truly need 50 examples, or would fewer suffice? The purpose for gherkin is to allow your tests to be "business facing" which means they are readable by the stakeholders. 50 examples may clutter the real logic you are trying to test. You may want to consider a smaller, carefully chosen set of values that represent the diverse cases. I don't know your specific situation, so I may be incorrect, but thought I would offer that advice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary in your step definitions. When you say something like: "And that the K_STATUS_Fields are valid" and that you use a loop in your step definitions to go through all the values.

Is that a possible solution to you, or am I totally of on understanding the problem?

Comment: But then my rule won't be run against each dictionary value, will it?

Comment: Yes it will. The loop goes through your complete dictionary and will apply the rule(s) to every dictionary value.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your examples table/dictionary as a Background:

```
Background:
    Given the following table
    | value             | result      |
    | 0                 | xxx         |
    | 1                 | yyy         |

Scenario: Scenario 1
    When something is done <value>
    And ...
    Then...
Scenario: Scenario 2
    When ...
    And ...
    Then...
```

Then:

```
    [Given(@"the following table")]
    public void GivenTheFollowingTable(Table table)
    {
        foreach (var row in table.Rows)
        {
            //fill up the dictionary
        }

        //add dictionary to Context
        ScenarioContext.Current.Add("ScenarioName", scenarioName);
    }

    [When(@"something is done")]
    public void WhenSomethingIsDone(string value)
    {
        //Get dictionary from Context
        var myDictionary = ScenarioContext.Current.Get<Dictionary<string,string>>("MyDictionary");

        //do something
    }
```

Comment: So it's more like "when I run my rule against each valid value of a dictionary" - do I get it right?

Comment: I'm new to this so might be missing something, but table does have GetEnumerator(), so you can't use a foreach? I'm guessing we'll need to do a CreateSet first to create an enumerable?